# IE8 asks to Open/Save twice on .xls file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, internet-explorer-8

I'm generating an Excel document via Servlet. When I send the response back to the client (IE8), the "Open/Save" dialog pops up but requires users to click a choice twice before taking action. This doesn't happen in Firefox. I have no idea why this is occurring. Below is the relevant code that creates the appropriate streams.

`result` contains the Excel XML.

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=TestFile.xls");

InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

try
{
    byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];

    while(in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1)
        out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
}
finally
{
    in.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

**EDIT**
I have noticed that waiting 5+ seconds before clicking an option works just fine. It seems to only ask twice when immediately clicking an option.

Comment: Seems to be a bug for IE: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=http://support.microsoft.com:80/support/kb/articles/q238/5/88.asp&NoWebContent=1, http://forums.asp.net/t/273944.aspx/1

Comment: I found those same references but they are quite old. I had hoped that maybe it was fixed in the last 5 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works well for every type of file in my application

```
  InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream();
  // Output the blob to the HttpServletResponse

  String codedfilename = "";
  //this code resolves the issue with the encoding of the downloaded filename
  String agent = request.getHeader("USER-AGENT");
  if (null != agent && -1 != agent.indexOf("MSIE"))
  {
    codedfilename = URLEncoder.encode(/*here goes the filename*/, "UTF8");
    response.setContentType("application/x-download");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=" + codedfilename);
  }
  else if (null != agent && -1 != agent.indexOf("Mozilla"))
  {
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    //It does not seem to make a difference whether Q or B is chosen
    codedfilename = MimeUtility.encodeText(rset.getString("FILE_NAME"), "UTF8", "B");
    response.setContentType("application/force-download");
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + codedfilename + "\"");
  }

  BufferedOutputStream out =
      new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
  byte by[] = new byte[32768];
  int index = in.read(by, 0, 32768);
  while (index != -1) {
      out.write(by, 0, index);
      index = in.read(by, 0, 32768);
  }
  out.flush();
```

try it and let us know

Comment: Didn't make a difference. Although I should mention that I have noticed that waiting 5+ seconds before clicking an option works just fine. It seems to only ask twice when immediately clicking an option.

Comment: using user agent can be tricky, they pretending each other - http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/ . Some older Opera used MSIE inside its agent.

Comment: Got me going in the right direction, but still haven't solved the problem.

Comment: what progress have you made so far?

Comment: Well, I've learned that simply waiting 5+ seconds before clicking "Open/Save" will stop the dialog from prompting twice. If you click an option immediately, it will ask twice. At this point I just have to accept it and move on.